# unable to click login button while testing on IE

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

while testing on IE page is open and field like username and password is filled but not clicking login button. I am unable to figure out the issues.

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",AbsoluteDriverPath); 
 webdriver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
   webdriver.get(URL);
  webdriver.manage().window().maximize();
    webdriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 webdriver.findElement(By.id("Text1")).sendKeys(user);
 webdriver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(password);
webdriver.findElement(By.id("ButtonLogin")).click();
```

Comment: Please post DOM structure of login form also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code :

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",AbsoluteDriverPath); 
     webdriver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
     webdriver.get(URL);
     webdriver.manage().window().maximize();
     webdriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     webdriver.findElement(By.id("Text1")).sendKeys(user);
     webdriver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(password);
     try{
        if (webdriver.findElement(By.id("ButtonLogin")).isDisplayed())
      {
        webdriver.findElement(By.id("ButtonLogin")).submit();
      }

     else{

        System.out.println("Submit button is not display");  
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: @DEO KUMAR DAS: Are you still acing issue?

Comment: Thank you so much this code works and able to Login.Can you explain me what the hack is this ??

Comment: I tried to logout using Xpath but it is giving javascript error driver.switchTo().frame("brandingTop");
       
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Logout')]")).submit();

Comment: Can you provide me your link?

Comment: Try this one  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Logout')]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

> Use Click method -->

```
webdriver.findElement(By.id("ButtonLogin")).click();
```